# Populating a Listbox with array containing more than 10 columns - getting rows instead of columns

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, listbox, populate

I am using a Listbox to show order data in an inventory management system.

The Ordernumber is typed into the textbox. Hitting CommandButton1 Searches for the corresponding value in the Table. Then the Row number of the found record is being used to fill the array with values

the following option does not work, since the Listbox Element in VBA is limited to 10 columns

```html
With ListBox2
  ListBox2.ColumnCount = 10
  .AddItem
  .List(listBoxPos, 0) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "A").Value 
  .List(listBoxPos, 1) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "C").Value
  '... 
  .List(listBoxPos, 9) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "R").Value
End With
```

Unfortunately i need more than 10 columns. These columns are not within a Range (not next to each other, some are not needed)

I need the following columns A,C,D,E,S,T,U,V,W,R (F to P are processed by other method and written into 2 variables)

For now i tried to form an Array and write the values

```html
Dim rZelle        As Range
Dim sSuchbegriff  As String
Dim listBoxPos  As Integer
Dim matchcodeLs As String
Dim matchcodeNew As String



'Variables for each item that is going to be added to ListBox
Dim matchcodePos As String
Dim bestnr As String
Dim artnr As String
Dim farbcode As String
Dim bemerkung As String
Dim ordertyp As String
Dim lieferdat As String
Dim hzlt As String
Dim kommision As String
Dim fnr As String
Dim size As String
Dim amount As String

'Arrays that i tried to use to populate ListBox
Dim auftrpos(12) As String
Dim auftrpos2() As Variant


'Checks if value exists in TextBox
If Trim$(TextBox1.Value) <> "" Then
    sSuchbegriff = Trim$(TextBox1.Value)
Else
    MsgBox "Sie müssen einen Suchbegiff eingeben!", _
    48, "   Hinweis für " & Application.UserName
    Exit Sub
End If
'Search in the Column A of Table for Value from TextBox
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Columns(1)

'sets variable rZelle with found value
Set rZelle = .Find(What:=sSuchbegriff, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    'when value is found
    If Not rZelle Is Nothing Then


        '(other code and stuff....)
        
        
                    'Going through column F to P and filling Variable Amount and Size
                    
                    If Not Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "F").Value = "" Then
                        'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ind + 3, "C").Value = 34
                        size = "34"
                        amount = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "F").Value
                    End If
                    
                    '(........ ....... ....)
                    
                    If Not Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "P").Value = "" Then
                        'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ind + 3, "C").Value = ""
                        size = "X"
                        amount = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "P").Value
                    End If
                    
            
            
                    'Populating the first array
                    auftrpos(0) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "A").Value
                    auftrpos(1) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "C").Value
                    auftrpos(2) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "D").Value
                    auftrpos(3) = size
                    auftrpos(4) = amount
                    auftrpos(5) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "E").Value
                    auftrpos(6) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "S").Value
                    auftrpos(7) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "T").Value
                    auftrpos(8) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "U").Value
                    auftrpos(9) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "V").Value
                    auftrpos(10) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "W").Value
                    auftrpos(11) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "R").Value
                    
                    
                   'populating the second array
                    
                    auftrpos2 = Array(Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "A").Value, Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "C").Value, Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "D").Value, size, amount, Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "E").Value, Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "S").Value, Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "T").Value, Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "U").Value, Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "V").Value, auftrpos(10) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "W").Value, auftrpos(11) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "R").Value)
                    
                  
                    
                    With UserForm1.ListBox2
                        .ColumnCount = 12
                        
                        '.List = Application.Transpose(auftrpos2)
                        '.List = Application.Transpose(auftrpos)
                        '.List = auftrpos2
                        '.List = auftrpos
                    End With
                                
End Sub
```

i tried populating the ListBox in several ways but i always end up getting rows instead of columns

Comment: You need a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this did the trick ^^ :) thanks for showing me the right path!
But i am not there yet, when i want to add a second position the first entry gets replaced by the new one instead of being added, how can one achieve this?

```html
Dim auftrpos4(0, 12) As String

                    auftrpos4(0, 0) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "A").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 1) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "C").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 2) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "D").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 3) = size
                    auftrpos4(0, 4) = amount
                    auftrpos4(0, 5) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "E").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 6) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "S").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 7) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "T").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 8) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "U").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 9) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "V").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 10) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "W").Value
                    auftrpos4(0, 11) = Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(rZelle.Row, "R").Value
                    
With UserForm1.ListBox2
  .ColumnCount = 12
  .List = auftrpos4
End With
```

Comment: Not sure if you ever got to your answer, but you should be able to "ReDim Preserve auftrpos4"